# Tabbar getting displaced often

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, badge

I've been seeing this strange behaviour of `UITabbar`where it gets shifted to left leaving a big `padding` as shown in the image attached. 
[image]

I'm not quite sure what might be causing this. Below is the only code where I'm making a change to the badge position:

```
func repositionBadge(tab: Int){

for badgeView in tabBarController!.tabBar.subviews[tab].subviews {

    if NSStringFromClass(badgeView.classForCoder) == "_UIBadgeView" {
        badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        badgeView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-3.0, -10.0, 1.0)
    }
}
```

and calling it                         `self.repositionBadge(tab: 3)`

Any idea on what might be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set autolayout ?

Comment: @AbhishekMitra I'm using UITabbarController. Hence no autolayout :)

Comment: If you are using `UITabbarController` then it shouldn't be happen like this, are you sure it is not a custom tabview ?

Comment: @AbhishekMitra Yup. Double sure. Its `UITabbarController` and not custom

Comment: when do you call your function?

Comment: @JuicyFruit Once I get response from the server

Comment: @Sreejith try to call this func in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` or `layoutSubviews()` after execution

Comment: @JuicyFruit Thanks. Will try this. Btw I really don't know whether this piece of code is creating the problem.

Comment: It is not about the code but how iOS works with layout. Did it help?